# Can i declare and use the same button in an Activity and a class?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to use the button for different calls in the different classes. However, when I declare and try to call the Button click method in the Activity class, it throws a null exception. In my **Class I want to do this:**

```
public class CustomFeedListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


       holder.feedUpVoteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUpVoteButton);

        holder.feedUpVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                  //do stuff

                   }
                     });


    private class ViewHolder {

    Button feedUpVoteButton;

}
```

And in my **main activity I want to do this:**

```
public class Feed extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button upVoteButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

      upVoteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feedUpVoteButton);

    feedUpVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //do stuff

               }
                 });


  }
 }
```

Comment: No problem you can.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I would get a null error for my `button.setOnClick` method in my MainActivity?

Comment: Please share activity_feed.

Comment: do you want to access feedUpVoteButton from adapter to your activity ?

Comment: @Chirayu YES, exactly

Comment: @Chirayu It cannot be declared `static` because it is in a `ViewHolder` method

Comment: try using `setTag` and `getTag` approach. if you still not getting succeed let me know i will guide you.

Comment: yes i know... im not saying to set it as static

Comment: @Chirayu i need to use the button click method in main activity so i can call `notifydatasetchanged` to the adapter

Comment: yes @espa_network i got your issue. u can exactly get what u want just search about `setTag` and `getTag` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NullPointerException because you are trying to access `feedUpVoteButton` which is present in the `item layout` used in `CustomFeedListViewAdapter` and not in the layout used by `Feed` activity.

Do you want to have access to the ClickListener whenever you create an adapter of type `CustomFeedListViewAdapter`? If yes then do this...

Your **Activity** class

```
public class Feed extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomFeedListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

        adapter = new CustomFeedListViewAdapter( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Handle click here
            }

        });

    }
}
```

And your **custom adapter** class

```
public class CustomFeedListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    View.OnClickListener clickListener;

    // Constructor
    public CustomFeedListViewAdapter(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        clickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    void getView(){

        holder.feedUpVoteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUpVoteButton);

        holder.feedUpVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //do stuff

            }
        });
    }

}
```

This way you can set a different listener for each instance of the adapter you create.